# Working with meteor wizard steps?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working with planficca wizard where the wizard steps are on top of my wizard such that press when I press "next" it moves to the next step. I want the steps to be over to the left of the step body. My wizard currently looks like this:

[image]

But I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: I would ask the author for a [feature request](https://github.com/Planifica/meteor-wizard/issues) , providing a configuration parameter for the steps / breadcrumb locations.

Comment: Thank you...How to know weather the package is updated...?